# SQL query to find values based on selected date, but will find the latest value if there's no value on the selected date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the branch values of the current date, but if there's no value for the current date, get the value of its latest reading.

For example, the selected date is September 29, 2013.

I have three branches.

Two of those branches has sales value for September 29, 2013.

One branch does not have encoded values, but this branch has a latest value date August 30, 2013.

In other words,

```
Branch 1 - Sep 29 - value is 150
Branch 2 - Sep 29 - value is 150
Branch 3 - Sep 29 - value is 0
```

I cannot just do 150 + 150 + 0 = 300

What I have to do is:

```
Branch 1 - Sep 29 - value is 150
Branch 2 - Sep 29 - value is 150
Branch 3 - Sep 29 - value is 0, so find the latest reading, system finds August 30 with value 250.
```

So now I can do 150 + 150 + 250 = 550

Currently, I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, product_code, uom, inventory_date, account_id, branch_id, beginning_inventory 

FROM 
    inventory_mgmt_uploads 

WHERE 
    user_id = '137'
    AND product_code = 'GRO_AL'
    AND uom = 'box'
    AND account_id = '3'
    AND inventory_date <= '2013-09-29'

ORDER BY
    inventory_date
```

The result of the query above is:

[image]

Now what I want to achieve is this result:

[image]

What I've tried is this query:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, product_code, uom, inventory_date, account_id, branch_id, beginning_inventory 

FROM 
    inventory_mgmt_uploads 

WHERE 
    user_id = '137'
    AND product_code = 'GRO_AL'
    AND uom = 'box'
    AND account_id = '3'
    AND inventory_date <= '2013-09-29'

GROUP BY
    branch_id

ORDER BY
    inventory_date
```

But it gives me:

[image]

Even if I tried to do an order by branch_id desc, or inventory_date desc, I still can't get my desired output.
Any ideas what will be the correct query? TIA!

Comment: Can you show us in [SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for simplicity

Comment: @Romesh, sure, here is my schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b9363/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this also:

```
SELECT a.USER_ID, a.PRODUCT_CODE, a.UOM, MAX(a.INVENTORY_DATE), a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.BRANCH_ID, (
  SELECT BEGINNING_INVENTORY FROM test 
  WHERE user_id = a.user_id
  AND product_code = a.product_code
  AND uom = a.uom
  AND inventory_date = MAX(a.inventory_date)
  AND account_id = a.account_id
  AND branch_id = a.branch_id
) as BEGINNING_INVENTORY
FROM test as a
WHERE a.INVENTORY_DATE <= '2013-09-29'
GROUP BY a.USER_ID, a.product_code, a.uom, a.account_id, a.branch_id
```

The query mentioned by Sashi Kant worked correctly because you have sequential data (beginning_inventory decreases with date). If the data was scrambled, the above approach won't give correct data.

Comment: Check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe824/5 and let me know if it's correct or not

Comment: Thanks, but you got the wrong dates and beginning inventory values, please see my desired result above.. also note that I changed the value of 302 to 316 in my table..

Comment: Your query works! but it will be better if you'll add more explanation why it works to make us understand it better!

Comment: In the above query, I've grouped by all fields except the inventory_date field, I've picked the max for it. For the rest of the fields, it will return the combination of all those grouped fields with max of inventory_date field, and then I've used an inner query to get the beginning_inventory for the particular data returned (with max inventory_date)

Comment: You can try changing the groups to get the result you want. In the above query, it will return a row for each field combination because I've grouped with all fields except inventory_date and beginning_inventory. Perhaps that's why it is returning more results.

Comment: will you still help me? here is a fiddle with my original table, it returns 20 rows.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40213/2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39052/discussion-between-vishal-deep-and-mico)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select * from inventory_mgmt_uploads outerimu 
INNER JOIN 
  (  SELECT 
        user_id, MIN(inventory_date) as minInvent, branch_id as Bid, MIN(beginning_inventory) as Binvent

    FROM 
        inventory_mgmt_uploads 

    WHERE 
        user_id = '137'
        AND product_code = 'GRO_AL'
        AND uom = 'box'
        AND account_id = '3'
        AND inventory_date <= '2013-09-29'

    GROUP BY
        branch_id
) as tempTab
    on (tempTab.user_id = outerimu.user_id and tempTab.minInvent=outerimu.inventory_date AND tempTab.Binvent =outerimu.beginning_inventory and tempTab.Bid= outerimu.branch_id)
    ORDER BY
    inventory_date
```